# CakePHP: How do I load associated data from inside an entity class?

Tags: php, cakephp

Let's say I have a AuthorsTable with a defined "belongs to many" association with the Articles table defined like so:

```
// In the initialize function of the AuthorsTable class.
$this->belongsToMany('Articles',
    ['joinTable' => 'authors_articles']
);
```

(I don't think that the nature of the join is relevant to the question, but just in the interest of giving full context.)

And now, a I have an `$author` entity that was passed to my function that does not have the associated data loaded with it (i.e., it was created using something like `$author = $authorsTable->get(19);`, so it only has the information in the `authors` table, not from the `articles` table.

Is there some kind of entity function in which I can load the associated data, i.e., the `articles` data *after* the entity has already been created?

Comment: you can use contain to get associated data.

Comment: Can you specify which CakePHP version do you use?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka-- I'm talking about from within the entity.  I can't seem to find a way to get contain to work apart from the find method of the table class.

Comment: @SamHecquet Newest one as of this writing-- 3.4.

Comment: Can't you create the variable like this since the beginning: 
$author = $authorsTable->get(19, [
    'contain' => ['articles']
]);

Comment: @SamHecquet I can't guarantee that the entity being passed to my function will always be created that way.  That's why I'm asking the question I did and not that question.

Answer (score 4):

chriss's answer suggests using loadInto for this. For CakePHP 3, the PHP you need within any Author Entity method is:

```
TableRegistry::get($this->source())->loadInto($this, ['Articles']);
```

The same code from within an AuthorsTable method:

```
$this->loadInto($author, ['Articles']);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit over and I do not know if it's still important to you, but maybe for everyone else. 
You can either use the model's `loadInto` (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#loading-additional-associations) or you can just use the Lazy Loading Plugin, mentioned in the docs (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#lazy-loading-associations)

You can find the plugin here:
https://github.com/jeremyharris/cakephp-lazyload

The plugin works with both methods! If you prefer **Eager Loading**, you can use `contain` (normaly faster). Otherwise, the associations will be loaded "on demand" (saving memory).

Personally, I prefer **Eager Loading** but use the **Lazy Loading Plugin** if another member of the team (out of ignorance) forgot to load the Associations.